# Why does 'ctrl + left mouse button' not work when opening recent?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to open a recent workspace in a new window, however, the 'ctrl + left mouse button' doesn't work now. Is there any update with this feature? How can I open workspace in a new window without closing the old window?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: ctrl + Enter doesn't work.